# How to make a skinnable ipad game with downloadable skins?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

I'm new to stackoverflow so forgive me if i sound a bit clueless.

I'm currently making a game for the iPad for my final year project at uni and would like to make it skinnable, different fonts, backgrounds, counters etc. but would like different skins to be downloadable separate to the app.

What would be the best way of implementing this?

thanks in advance